# Speed=distance by time python code division syntax error

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime

start = input("Press enter to start")
starttime =(datetime.now())
stop = input("Press enter to stop")
stoptime =(datetime.now())
dist1 = 0
dist2 = input("enter dist2:")
time = stoptime-starttime
print(time)
distance = int(dist2) - dist1
print(distance)
speed = int(distance)% time
print(speed)
```

Syntax error coming in second last line

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Please help me fix that so that I can calculate the speed with the help of the stop watch timer.

Comment: What does that error message mean to you? What do you think the problem is?

Comment: i think that the time is coming in this format 0:00:00.000000 and it is not able to divide with the distance

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but just so you know, `%` is not the division operator. Did you mean to use `/`?

Comment: Beyond the error that you're getting, I'd take a look at the difference between _modulo_ and _division_.

Comment: There is no syntax error here; you have a *runtime* error instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

In your line:

```
speed = int(distance) % time
```

You are trying to use the modulo operator on an `int` and a `datetime` object, which you got using the `.now()` method.

If you want to convert the time to seconds, you should do that using the `total_seconds()` method.

I.E.

```
time = (stoptime - starttime).total_seconds()
```

This will return an integer you can use in your division, or currently your modulo

Comment: how do u use it please help me i know very less on datetime functions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `time` module? (Note: your `speed` would be is `m/s` provided the `distance` you input is in `metres`)

```
import time
print time.time()
start = input("Press enter to start: ")
starttime =time.time()
stop = input("Press enter to stop")
stoptime =time.time()
dist1 = 0
dist2 = input("enter dist2:")
time = stoptime-starttime
print(time)
distance = int(dist2) - dist1
print(distance)
speed = int(distance)/ time
print(speed)
```

Answer (score -1):

print ("speed=distance/time")

#1) first we put the distance input in a variable
d = input ("what is the distance? (miles)")

#2) then we must substitute the time input, it is measured in number of hours
t = input ("what is the time?(hours): ")

#3) after substituting both inputs, we must calculate the average speed in kilometers per hour, we calculate by dividing 500 and 10
input ("speed in kilometers per hour: ")

#4) Finally, we conclude the equation with a full sentence, which will also print the output
print ("in order to travel 500 km in 10 hours, you must travel at 50.0 km/h")

Comment: the answer has nothing to deal with quesion, please consider helping author with the TypeError